Probability "simple" question
I'm struggling on how can I solve the following problem. I tried with a lot of calculus without success, but i think that the way to solve is:
P(at least one failure)=1−P(no failures in both selections).
Here is the problem:
A manufacturer produces three types of lamps: A, B, and C. The probabilities of each type of lamp failing during testing are as follows:
P(A fail) = 0.1

P(B fail) = 0.2

P(C fail) = 0.05

A package contains 2 type A lamps, 3 type B lamps and 4 type C lamps. If two lamps are selected at random, what is the probability that at least one of them will fail?

Anyone could give me a hint on how can I calculate this?

You are correct in that the right approach to solve this is to calculate $P(\text{at least one failure}) = 1 - P(\text{no failures in both conditions})$.
In order to calculate this, you can start by first calculating the probability of each possible combination of types of lamps. Then, you calculate the probability that $0$ lamps will fail in each of those conditions. Finally, you multiply the probability of obtaining each combination of lamps by the probability that $0$ lamps will fail in each of those conditions, and sum them together to obtain $P(\text{no failures in both conditions})$. After this, you subtract the result from 1 and you are done.
To use an example, let's take one possible outcome, which is that you first pull out one type A lamp, then pull out one type B lamp. This is $P(\text{choose A and B})$. (Note that this is choosing without replacement, since I am assuming that is what you are going for.) The probability of first pulling out a type A lamp from the package is $\frac{2}{2+3+4} = \frac{2}{9}$, since there are 2 type A lamps in the package. Then, the probability of pulling out a type B lamp after that is $\frac{3}{1+3+4} = \frac{3}{8}$. Thus, the probability of pulling out a type A lamp followed by a type B lamp (without replacement, assuming each lamp has an equal probability of being chosen) is $\frac{2}{9} \times \frac{3}{8} = \frac{6}{72} = \frac{1}{12} = 0.08\overline{3}$.
Then, calculate the probability that neither of these lamps will fail, given this condition. This is $P(\text{neither fail}|\text{choose A and B})$. Note that this is equivalent to $[1 - P(\text{A fail})] \times [1 - P(\text{B fail})] = (1-0.1)\times(1-0.2) = 0.9\times0.8 = 0.72$.
Then, the 'component' of the ultimate probability $P(\text{no failures in both conditions})$ that is made up of the case where we choose A and B is $P(\text{choose A and B})P(\text{neither fail}|\text{choose A and B}) = 0.08\overline{3}\times0.72 = 0.06$. Once you calculate each of the 'components' for each possible case of pairs of lamps, you can sum them together to obtain $P(\text{no failures in both conditions})$. Then, calculate $P(\text{at least one failure}) = 1 - P(\text{no failures in both conditions})$ and you have your answer.

Let the random variable $Y$ correspond to which lamps are selected from the package. That is,
$$Y = \begin{cases} 
y_1 := \mathsf{AA} & \text{w.p. } p_1 \\
y_2 := \mathsf{AB} & \text{w.p. } p_2 \\
y_3 := \mathsf{AC} & \text{w.p. } p_3 \\
y_4 := \mathsf{BB} & \text{w.p. } p_4 \\
y_5 := \mathsf{BC} & \text{w.p. } p_5 \\
y_6 := \mathsf{CC} & \text{w.p. } p_6 
\end{cases}$$
$p_1$ is the probability of sampling two $\mathsf{A}$ lamps from the package, ie.
$$p_1 = \frac{2}{9} \times \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{36}$$
Let $X$ be the event that at least one lamp fails and $\mathbf{1}_{X}$ the associated indicator variable (takes on value 1 if $X$ occurs and 0 otherwise).
By the law of total expectation
$$\Pr( X ) = \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_X \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{X} \mid Y \right] \right] = \sum_{i=1}^6 \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{X} \mid Y = y_i \right] p_i = \sum_{i=1}^6 \Pr\left( X \mid Y = y_i \right) p_i$$
The problem is now reduced to computing the probability that at least one lamp fails given which two lamps are tested.
